# Как называется технология принудительного показа веб-страницы пользователю сети?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, фильтрация

В моей сети фильтрация по mac-адресу. Если подключиться к этой сети с устройства, mac-адрес которого не внесен в базу, то на этом устройстве принудительно открывается браузер по умолчанию со страницей, уведомляющей о том, что нужно обратиться к администратору для внесения вашего устройства в базу. Как называется технология, позволяющая при определенных обстоятельствах принудительно показывать любому пользователю сети заданную веб-страницу? И что нужно для реализации чего-то подобного?

Comment: "технология" называется `фильтрация трафика по mac-адресу и протоколу (порту назначения) с преобразованием (например, DNAT) трафика по условию`. Для реализации нужен "роутер" (железка, линукс-хост, etc) который умеет реализовывать такую "технологию".

Comment: С фильтрацией мне все понятно, это делается элементарно, как принудительно открыть веб-страницу любому пользователю сети?

Answer (score 1):

Нашла наконец: такая технология называется captive portal!